# SKSpriteNodes are showing up different sizes on a real iPhone

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, size

I am making an app, and recently, out of the blue there has been a problem.
When I ran my app on my iPhone, (which I have been doing fine for the last few weeks) the images show up at completely different sizes.

For example:
The start button on the Xcode simulator is `xScale 2.0f`. On the iPhone it shows to be roughly half that size. I keep all the images in a `.atlas` file, and they are all `.png`. I am using sprite kit as well, and the iPhone I am using is on iOS 7.

Here is what I'm getting:
[Unwanted result (As is on iPhone)](http://gyazo.com/13b2988a768d7d8d629f6cd1993b9659)

Here is what I would like:
[Desired Result (As is on simulator)](http://gyazo.com/dbaa80a7da8eb01d1952566e003dc09e)

This has also happened throughout the app, with other sprite nodes. Does anyone know how I can fix this problem? Thank you in advance, and I would have posted screenshots if it wasn't for the 10 rep limit.

**Edit**:
I have now got most of the images working, by creating a @2x version of all the images.

But there is still one graphic that is this time **TOO LARGE** on the iPhone. Thank you for all your help so far, does anyone know how I can make that one image smaller on the iPhone?

Comment: Are you using images with 2x or 3x versions?

Comment: For each image, there is one version of 1x, and one version of 2x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PNGs need to be labeled with a 2x or 3x.  This is Apples way of accounting for the retina screens.

"ImageFileName@2x.png"
for Iphone 4,5,6

"ImageFileName@3x.png"
for Iphone 6 Plus

If you have no extension, Apple will assume it should make your image 2 or 3 times bigger to account for the extra pixels in the retina displays.  If you add the @2x or @3x, Apple assumes you provided the image already accounting for the retina pixel count.

Comment: Thank you, I added a 2x image for all of them, and it means that all but one of the images run smoothly on the iPhone. Apart from 1 graphic, that now doubles in size when I run it on the iPhone. This one graphic has a 1x and 2x. Do you know how I can fix it?

Comment: If you want to support the current Iphones, you need a copy of each image that is 2x and 3x.  When you assign the image to a texture you do not include the @2x.  For example sprite = [spritenode spritewimage: @"imagename"];   spritekit will pick the appropriate image with the correct extension for that iphone.